# Assign a default value when using the NEW Null-Conditional operator shorthand feature in .Net?

Tags: vb.net, null, conditional-statements, visual-studio-2015

The new Null-conditional operator shorthand feature in .Net enables us write neat code like this:

```
Dim x = customer.Address?.Country
```

If `customer.Address` is null, does the new Language feature offer a way to supply default values?

Presently i use the following code:

```
Dim x = If(customer.Address is nothing, "No Address", customer.Address?.Country)
```

Comment: I haven't installed VS2015 yet, but perhaps `Dim x = If(customer.Address?.Country, "No Address")`?

Comment: i understand your code, but  i am asking about the new feature for 2015

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Or` operator.
This operator determines whether the variable is valid, and if it's *not*, assign the `or`'ed value.

In your case, you could use:

```
Dim x = customer.Address.Country Or "No Address"
```

Instead of

```
Dim x = If(customer.Address is nothing, "No Address", customer.Address?.Country)
```

Of course, that *does* mean these variables can have multiple types; you should perform additional checks to ensure the different object types do not break your program.

Another example (`DomainId` is `1`):

```
Dim num = System.Threading.Thread.GetDomainID() Or 0
Console.WriteLine(CStr(num))
Console.Read()
```

*The console writes out `1`, as it's valid*

However if we switch it around so `0 Or System.Threading.Thread.GetDomainID()` is used, we'll still get `1` as `0` isn't seen as 'valid'.

If *both* values are valid, then the rightmost variable is used.

Comment: thanks Bob, but I was hoping for a Language shorthand that would do this. Would really be a great convenience

Comment: @CharlesO Unfortunately I don't think there is... at least if there *is* I haven't found it via Google, nor do I have any knowledge of it. The `Or` method is as good as you can get in regard to this.

Comment: Are you sure this compiles?  `Or` is either a bitwise or when used with integers or a logical or when used with `Boolean`s  How are you using it with strings?  I don't think `x` will be what you think it will be, unless I'm just missing something.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Yes, it does compile. I always test my code before I submit an answer. If the `String` is `nil`, the other value will always be chosen.

Comment: With the `Or` operator? How does the `Or` operator work like that on strings?  Do you have `Option Strict On`?  When I try to compile that line of code, I get `Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'String' to 'Long'.`.

Comment: And when I turn `Option Strict Off` I get `An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` at runtime so I cannot understand how you are getting that line to compile.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: For that test, VS 2013 Premium

Comment: @ChrisDunaway This question asks in the scope of the **latest version of VB.NET**, not the earlier version which you are using. I used Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise for this.

Comment: Has the `Or` operator changed in the newest version?  I have not seen any articles mentioning any such change.  Note that I am only referring to the first line of code in your answer.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Unsure, there's no documentation for the change but I've been using the same thing in Lua for years, I decided to try it recently in VB.NET and it worked.